# Disallow to remove a product with a specific ID from WooCommerce cart if another product is added

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I have to implement the following logic to my Cart / Checkout pages:

If the product with `ID="100"` is in the Cart I need to disallow its removal from Cart if the Product with `ID="101"` was also added.

In simple words, the ability to remove a product is only present if a product with a specific ID was not added.

Earlier I used the following solution to disallow product removal only for specific product IDs. But this code doesn't work with variable products and I can't get how to implement my logic inside it.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', 'customized_cart_item_remove_link', 20, 2 );
function customized_cart_item_remove_link( $button_link, $cart_item_key ){
    $targeted_products_ids = array( 98,99,100 );

    $cart_item = WC()->cart->get_cart()[$cart_item_key];

    if( in_array($cart_item['data']->get_id(), $targeted_products_ids) )
        $button_link = '';

    return $button_link;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer allows you if `product_id_1` is in the cart it will not be removable from the cart if `product_id_2` is also added.

This can be applied to multiple products via the `$settings` array, so a certain product cannot be removed if the corresponding product ID is in the cart.

For clarity, **this works based on the product ID** (simple) **or the parent ID** (variable) products. If you want to apply it for variations of variable products you don't have to use `get_parent_id()`.

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link( $link, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Settings (multiple settings arrays can be added/removed if desired)
    $settings = array(
        array(
            'product_id_1'  => 100,
            'product_id_2'  => 101,
        ),
        array(
            'product_id_1'  => 30,
            'product_id_2'  => 813,
        ),
        array(
            'product_id_1'  => 53,
            'product_id_2'  => 817,
        ),
    );
    
    // Get cart
    $cart = WC()->cart;
    
    // If cart
    if ( $cart ) {
        // Get cart item
        $cart_item = $cart->get_cart()[$cart_item_key];
        
        // Get parent/real ID
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_parent_id() != 0 ? $cart_item['data']->get_parent_id() : $cart_item['data']->get_id();
        
        // Loop trough settings array
        foreach ( $settings as $key => $setting ) {
            // Compare, get the correct setting array
            if ( $product_id == $settings[$key]['product_id_1'] ) {
                // Cart id of the other product
                $product_cart_id = $cart->generate_cart_id( $settings[$key]['product_id_2'] );
                
                // Find other product in cart
                $in_cart = $cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
                
                // When true
                if ( $in_cart ) {
                    // Hide remove button
                    $link = '';
                    
                    // Break loop
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', 10, 2 );
```